# Passing data between two flutter classes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling the below class:

```
`HomePage(encryptedCipher: args as Uint8List))`
```

I am passing encryptedCipher (important secret)

In the HomePage:

```
`class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Uint8List encryptedCipher;

  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.encryptedCipher}) : super(key:key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}`
```

In _HomePageState() class, I am accessing it via the below method:

```
  `@override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   encryptedCipher = widget.encryptedCipher;
}`
```

Question: Is this safe and can a hacker have access to encryptedCipher, while it is passed between classes?

I tried doing research on if this method is safe, but have not been able to find helpful articles.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to pass an encrypted value like `encryptedCipher` between two classes as long as the encryption method used is secure and the key used to encrypt the data is kept secret.

Accessing the `encryptedCipher` via the `widget` property in the `_HomePageState` class is also safe since the `widget` property is only accessible within the context of the `State` object and is not accessible outside of it.

And since `encryptedCipher` is not stored in the memory of the device in a way that would allow an attacker to access it, then you should not be concerned about this.

Comment: How about decryptedCipher? can we decrypt it at login screen and pass the secret to home page?